# Safely extend TCNT1 / ICR1 to 24 bits using TOV1

Tags: interrupt, atmega328, timers

I'm hoping to time external events on a '328p Arduino that will occur slowly enough that they'll overflow the 16-bit counter TCNT1. In a different scenario I'd prescale the counter, but I need the full timer resolution in this case for other purposes.

So I enable the TOV1 interrupt and just increment an 8-bit value, letting it roll over as needed.

Then on an ICP1 interrupt, I shift this value << 16 into a 32-bit variable, and add in the value captured in ICR1, yielding a 24-bit value that I can use to measure the slow interval.

Are there hidden gotchas in this plan? Possible race conditions where TOV1 hasn't yet been updated if ICR1 is latched just when TCNT1 has just rolled over, or generates a TOV1 after capturing ICR1 but before I shift in the overflow count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, indeed, a possible race condition. Consider this naive code,
which provides 32-bit timestamps:

```cpp
/* Count overflows. */
volatile uint16_t timer1_overflow_count;
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    timer1_overflow_count++;
}

/* Timestamp input events. */
volatile uint32_t captured_timestamp;
volatile bool did_capture;
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    captured_timestamp = timer1_overflow_count << 16 | ICR1;
    did_capture = true;
}
```

Since TIMER1_CAPT has higher priority than TIMER1_OVF, then:

- If `ICF1` rises before `TOV1`, `TIMER1_CAPT_vect` runs first, which
  is fine.
- If `ICF1` and `TOV1` rise simultaneously, `TIMER1_CAPT_vect` runs
  first, which is still fine, as the captured value is `0xffff`.
- If `TOV1` rises before `ICF1`, either ISR may run first:

  - if the CPU can process the TIMER1_OVF IRQ right away, then
    `TIMER1_OVF_vect` runs first and the result is correct
  - if the interrupt processing is delayed until after `ICF1` has
    risen, then `TIMER1_CAPT_vect` runs first and grabs a wrong value
    for `timer1_overflow_count`.

### Solution

There is an unhandled overflow when `bit_is_set(TIFR1, TOV1)`. The
overflow may have happened at the same time or after the capture, in
which case it doesn't affect the timestamp. We know it happened before
the capture when the captured value is small, where “small” could be
defined as having its most significant bit clear. If this is the case,
we have to add `0x10000` to the timestamp we obtained.

A race-proof ISR can be written as follows:

```cpp
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    uint16_t captured_low = ICR1;
    uint16_t captured_high = timer1_overflow_count;
    if (bit_is_set(TIFR1, TOV1) && !(captured_low & 0x8000)) {
        captured_high++;
    }
    captured_timestamp = (uint32_t) captured_high << 16 | captured_low;
    did_capture = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. I get everything about your solution except the phrase *we have to add `0x0100` to the timestamp*. In code you (effectively) add `0x10000`, which is what I'd expect for a missed overflow. Typo?

Comment: @JimMack: Oops! You are right, I made a typo. Fixed, thanks!